# Multiple errors attempting to solve a function with fsolve and sym solve in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, matlab

I am trying to solve the function below. I've attempted to use a symbolic solver and fsolve. Both are causing me trouble. First time posting, I apologize in advance if I'm missing something in my question.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to solve this? I am solving for y, everything else is a known variable.

`cos(y) + ((xi - tdd) / y) * sin(y)) - exp(xi - tii)`

I attempted this in python using two ways, both did not work. The first is:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import sympy as sym
from sympy import *

def fi(y):
    return ((cos(y) + ((xi - tdd) / y) * sin(y)) - exp(xi - tii))
y = fsolve(fi,0.01)
```

With this code I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'ImmutableDenseNDimArray' object has no attribute 'could_extract_minus_sign'

I also tried this:

```
y = symbols('y')
init_printing(use_unicode=True)
yi = solve(cos(y) + ((xi - tdd) / y) * sin(y)) - exp(xi - tii))
```

And got this error:

> NotImplementedError: multiple generators [y, tan(y/2)] No algorithms are implemented to solve equation y*(10000000000000000*(-tan(y/2)**2 + 1)/(tan(y/2)**2 + 1) - 9849605264665270) - 300789470669454*tan(y/2)/(tan(y/2)**2 + 1)

This is how I solved it in Matlab (i and j because I have x values in a matrix that need to be solve):

```
fi = @(y,x) (cos(y) + (((x-tdd)/y)*sin (y))) - exp((x - tii));
yi(i) = fzero(@(y) fi(y,xi(i,j)),.01);
```

Comment: "Did not work" is not helpful for understanding the issue. If you got errors, please show the full traceback. Otherwise, explain in what way it didn't work.

Comment: fair enough, sorry.  Here are the errors. For fsolve AttributeError: 'ImmutableDenseNDimArray' object has no attribute 'could_extract_minus_sign'  for solve NotImplementedError: multiple generators [y, tan(y/2)] No algorithms are implemented to solve equation y*(10000000000000000*(-tan(y/2)**2 + 1)/(tan(y/2)**2 + 1) - 9849605264665270) - 300789470669454*tan(y/2)/(tan(y/2)**2 + 1)

Comment: As far as the usage of `solve` is concerned, it seems that it just can't solve functions of this kind. See [this](https://docs.sympy.org/0.7.6/tutorial/solvers.html) documentation page for more detail.

Comment: I agree with you, @Saviour. That made me think that a numeric solver `fsolve` would be the appropriate approach... Is this how you would code `fsolve`  ?

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to know what you want. Once I fixed the syntax errors you had in the first example (indentation was wrong, some parentheses were mismatched), and put in some arbitrary values for `xi`, `tii`, and `tdd` (1, 2, and 3, respectively), I got an answer (with those values, `[-0.005625]`). So not sure if you're finding that answer to be incorrect (I can't verify the math since I don't know what you're trying to do) or if you just are struggling with the aforementioned errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already addressed in a comment, the `solve` function isn't geared to solve such equations. More information can be found [here](https://docs.sympy.org/0.7.6/tutorial/solvers.html).

Regarding `fsolve`, it appears that the problem is caused because you are using the `sin`, `cos` and `exp` functions from sympy. If you replace them with the functions from the `math` module the code should work.

Specifically, your code should look like this:

```
import math
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def fi(y):
    return ((math.cos(y) + ((xi - tdd) / y) * math.sin(y)) - math.exp(xi - tii))

y = fsolve(fi, 0.01)
```

Comment: I get the exact same solution using your code and using the OP's code once I fix their errors. I don't see anything wrong with the `sympy` version of those mathematical functions. (Except that `sympy` is known to be slower - not the stated issue here)

Comment: @HFBrowning Maybe it depends on the version of python? I used 2.7.15 and got the error using the `sympy` functions, yet didn't get the error with the `math` functions.

Comment: Perhaps, since I am using 3.6.5. If so though - yikes

Comment: @Saviour and @HFBrowning I really appreciate the help. Using the `math` module I was able to solve the equation with `fsolve`. Sorry again for not providing all the information. Will note for next time.

Comment: @Rei if you feel Saviour's suggestion answered your question then you can indicate this for others by accepting it (the check mark under the up/down option on their answer).